# Dropdowns on Edit Page Won't Retain Value if Not Re-Selected

Tags: data-binding, drop-down-menu, sql-update, razor-pages

I currently have 2 dropdowns on my CREATE page. When I select the dropdown values on my CREATE page and SUBMIT them, they bind to the database just fine. However, if I open my EDIT page to make edits to anything on the page (either the dropdowns themselves OR another field), the dropdowns revert back to ---select---. The only way they bind (with an updated value) is if I select something else in BOTH of them every time I make an edit. If I only make changes to one, the other will revert back to ---select ***---.

Here are some screenshots to further clarify:

After SUBMITING the CREATE contents, when I click on the EDIT page, I can see the initial values that binded just fine.

[image: DD initial create values]

Say, I want to update the Specialty. I change it to 'Anesthesiology' and click UPDATE. When I got back into EDIT again, here is what I see (note that the Res Type is now back to the default ---Select---:

[image: DD first edit result]

Now, if I just click UPDATE on that EDIT page without making any changes and then go back and view it, here is what I see (note that both dropdowns are back to their default ---Select---):
[image: DD second edit result]

What am I missing that is keeping these values from "sticking" during an edit?

Here is what I have for my EDIT Page Model:

```
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="InfoSite.Specialty"></label>
                        <select asp-for="InfoSite.Specialty" id="Select1" class="form-select"> 
                            <option value="">---Select Specialty---</option>
                            @if (Model.DisplayMDSpecialtyData != null)
                            {
                            @foreach(var item1 in Model.DisplayMDSpecialtyData)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item1.ID" selected="@(item1.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.Specialty?true:false)" disabled="@(item1.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.Specialty?true:false)">@item1.Description</option>
                                }
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="InfoSite.ResType"></label>                      
                        <select asp-for="InfoSite.ResType" id="Select2" class="form-select">
                            <option value="">---Select Residence Type---</option>
                            @if (Model.DisplayResTypeData != null)
                            {
                                @foreach (var item2 in Model.DisplayResTypeData)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item2.ID" selected="@(item2.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.ResType?true:false)" disabled="@(item2.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.ResType?true:false)">@item2.Description</option>
                                }
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

And here is what I have for my Edit.cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using PHECWeb.Data;
using PHECWeb.Model;

namespace PHECWeb.Pages.InfoSites;

[BindProperties]

public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public InfoSite InfoSite { get; set; }
    public EditModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MDSpecialty> DisplayMDSpecialtyData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ResType> DisplayResTypeData { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(int? ID)
    {
        InfoSite = _db.InfoSite.Find(ID);
        DisplayMDSpecialtyData = _db.MDSpecialty.ToList();
        DisplayResTypeData = _db.ResType.ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.InfoSite.Update(InfoSite);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Site Information updated successfully.";
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I can supply more info. I will continue to use the disclaimer that I am very new as this is still my very first application. Please understand this. I won't necessarily understand what you tell me if you just say "add xyz" and you don't tell me exactly WHERE I would need to add it and what it does. Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retain the values of the dropdowns when making ANY change to the edit page, one simply needs to remove this bit of HTML from each of the dropdown's code:

```
disabled="@(item1.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.Specialty?true:false)"
```